# Error - Schema is not configured for mutations, although mutation included in the schema

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

Although i have created a mutation and inserted it in graphql schema, it returns the error, Checked with other instances of same error there isn't any solution regarding the current issue

```
'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'articles' => App\GraphQL\Query\ArticlesQuery::class,
            ],
            'mutation' => [
                'updatearticle' => App\GraphQL\Mutation\UpdateArticle::class
            ],
            'middleware' => [],
            'method' => ['get', 'post'],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schema is not configured for mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882777/schema-is-not-configured-for-mutations)

Comment: @Bira there is more to flagging duplicayes than merely finding a page with the same keywords.  That "duplicate" page was a one-character typo -- I just voted to close it as Off-topic: typo.  If you see a typo in this new question, you should have voted Off-topic: typo and left an informative comment.  If you do not see a typo here, please retract your close flag.

Comment: not really a duplicate.. i have the same issue and the other solution does not help. in that case it was a simple misspell.. my queries work when i go directly to endpoints but not via geteway